# "on the coast" antonym?

Tags: word-request

I want to ask someone if his town on the coast or not.

> A: I'm living in X.
>   B: Is it on the coast or on the ____.

What is the antonym of "on the coast"? I don't think it is "on the land" because everything is on the land.

Comment: It's generally: *in the interior* or *inland*.

Comment: @RonaldSole - And, just to be clear, that's just _inland_, not _**on the** inland_)

Comment: @J.R. That's it. *I live inland* means not on the coast. *In the interior* is usually reserved for some distance from the coast, more often of a large country than a small one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The antonym of

> on the coast
>   coastal

meaning where *a large body of water and land meet*

might be

> inland
>   land-locked

meaning *on land, away from water* or *surrounded by land*

Your B question might be

> A: I'm living in X.
>
> B: Is it on the coast or inland?
>   B: Is it on the coast or land-locked?

Comment: Technically, New Hampshire, Mississippi, and Alabama are not land-locked (because small parts of these states are on the coast), but most of the area of these states is inland.

Answer (score 2):

**Inland.**

For example the Inland Empire area of regional Los Angeles.